# Unable to find the right port to connect PySerial to USB device on Windows 11

Tags: python, usb, pyserial

I'm trying to use the PySerial library on Windows 11 to connect to a USB device so I can communicate with it. However, I'm having trouble finding the right "address" to connect it too. I'm trying to run the following command to connect but I don't know what to pass into it as I'm not on Linux and can't use '/dev/ttyusb0':

```
device="" # Don't know what to put here
serial.Serial(device)
```

I tried first looking at my COM ports, but all I found was this (looks like random Bluetooth stuff):
[Device Manager Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLnkg.png)

I did manage to find the right device on device manager, but I have no idea how to interface with it since it's not a COM port:
[Device Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eypoo.png)

I also ran USB Device Tree Viewer to get a better picture and it only made me more confused. It looks like the device I want to interact with is controlled by a eXtensible Host Controller which can be seen here:
[USB Device Tree Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08wPz.png)

FYI, the device I want to interact with is connected to the HUB on port 5 of the eXtensible Host Controller as seen on USB Device Tree Viewer.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. If it'd be impossible to do what I want in pySerial, please direct me as to where I could research further.

Let me know if I can provide any more information that could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue by instead using pyUSB and looking up the device by vendorID and productID. As a side-effect, it made the interaction with the device a lot easier.